# pandas get column average/mean

Tags: python, pandas

I can't get the average or mean of a column in pandas. A have a dataframe. Neither of things I tried below gives me the average of the column `weight`

```
>>> allDF 
         ID           birthyear  weight
0        619040       1962       0.1231231
1        600161       1963       0.981742
2      25602033       1963       1.3123124     
3        624870       1987       0.94212
```

The following returns several values, not one:

```
allDF[['weight']].mean(axis=1)
```

So does this:

```
allDF.groupby('weight').mean()
```

Comment: `df.groupby('weight')` wasn't what you wanted, because it split the df into separate columns, each with a distinct value of weight. Instead of just `df['weight'].mean()`

Comment: allDF. weight.mean()

Answer (score 429, accepted):

If you only want the mean of the `weight` column, select the column (which is a Series) and call `.mean()`:

```
In [479]: df
Out[479]: 
         ID  birthyear    weight
0    619040       1962  0.123123
1    600161       1963  0.981742
2  25602033       1963  1.312312
3    624870       1987  0.942120

In [480]: df.loc[:, 'weight'].mean()
Out[480]: 0.83982437500000007
```

Comment: and what if I wanted to get a mean of each and every column?

Comment: @Chris         df.describe()

Comment: @Chris df.mean() gives you the weight of each column and returns it in a series.

Answer (score 43):

Try `df.mean(axis=0)` , `axis=0` argument calculates the column wise mean of the dataframe so the result will be `axis=1` is row wise mean so you are getting multiple values.

Comment: This works for most columns, but it will ignore any datetime columns.

Answer (score 23):

Do try to give `print (df.describe())` a shot. I hope it will be very helpful to get an overall description of your dataframe.

Comment: `display(df.describe())` is better (in Jupyter Notebooks) because `display` from ipython provides formatted HTML rather than ASCII, which is more visually useful/pleasing.

Answer (score 17):

Mean for each column in  `df` :

```
    A   B   C
0   5   3   8
1   5   3   9
2   8   4   9

df.mean()

A    6.000000
B    3.333333
C    8.666667
dtype: float64
```

and if you want average of all columns:

```
df.stack().mean()
6.0
```

Answer (score 15):

you can use

```
df.describe()
```

you will get basic statistics of the dataframe and to get mean of specific column you can use

```
df["columnname"].mean()
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of the answers mentioned above.

Answer (score 10):

You can also access a column using the dot notation (also called attribute access) and then calculate its mean:

```
df.your_column_name.mean()
```

Comment: Take `df.loc[:, 'your_column_name']` whenever you can.

Comment: @questionto42 why is that? why use df.loc[:, 'weight'].mean() instead of df['weight'].mean()?

Comment: @sparktime12 Both of the styles that you write here do the same, at the same speed. I just read (and vaguely remember) it as best practice since `loc` came up later and is standardised for anything you would like to query while the shortcut blurs the view on how the filter of a df works. Check [What is the difference between using loc and using just square brackets to filter for columns in Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411543/11154841).

Answer (score 6):

You can use either of the two statements below:

```py
numpy.mean(df['col_name'])
# or
df['col_name'].mean()
```

Comment: Please, enrich your answer with proper comments. Otherwise it is likely to be marked for deletion

Answer (score 4):

Do note that it needs to be in the numeric data type in the first place.

```
 import pandas as pd
 df['column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce')
```

Next find the mean on one column or for all numeric columns using `describe()`.

```
df['column'].mean()
df.describe()
```

Example of result from describe:

```
          column 
count    62.000000 
mean     84.678548 
std     216.694615 
min      13.100000 
25%      27.012500 
50%      41.220000 
75%      70.817500 
max    1666.860000
```

Comment: Take df.loc[:, 'your_column_name'] whenever you can.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally if you want to get the `round` value after finding the `mean`.

```
#Create a DataFrame
df1 = {
    'Subject':['semester1','semester2','semester3','semester4','semester1',
               'semester2','semester3'],
   'Score':[62.73,47.76,55.61,74.67,31.55,77.31,85.47]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['Subject','Score'])

rounded_mean = round(df1['Score'].mean()) # specified nothing as decimal place
print(rounded_mean) # 62

rounded_mean_decimal_0 = round(df1['Score'].mean(), 0) # specified decimal place as 0
print(rounded_mean_decimal_0) # 62.0

rounded_mean_decimal_1 = round(df1['Score'].mean(), 1) # specified decimal place as 1
print(rounded_mean_decimal_1) # 62.2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method `agg` (`aggregate`):

```
df.agg('mean')
```

It's possible to apply multiple statistics:

```
df.agg(['mean', 'max', 'min'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply go for:
        df.describe()
that will provide you with all the relevant details you need, but to find the min, max or average value of a particular column (say 'weights' in your case), use:

```
    df['weights'].mean(): For average value
    df['weights'].max(): For maximum value
    df['weights'].min(): For minimum value
```

Answer (score -2):

You can easily follow the following code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
        
classxii = {'Name':['Karan','Ishan','Aditya','Anant','Ronit'],
            'Subject':['Accounts','Economics','Accounts','Economics','Accounts'],
            'Score':[87,64,58,74,87],
            'Grade':['A1','B2','C1','B1','A2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(classxii,index = ['a','b','c','d','e'],columns=['Name','Subject','Score','Grade'])
print(df)

#use the below for mean if you already have a dataframe
print('mean of score is:')
print(df[['Score']].mean())
```