# compute mean of a column with python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df  :

```
TIMESTAMP equipement1 equipement2
2016-05-10 13:20:00 0.000000 0.000000
2016-05-10 14:40:00 0.400000 0.500000
2016-05-10 15:20:00 0.500000 0.500000
```

I would like to compute for each equipmeentx the ratio when timestamp in [TS_min, TS_max]
For example function :

```
def ratio(df, 2016-05-10 14:40:00, 2016-05-10 15:20:00)
TIMESTAMP equipement1 equipement2
2016-05-10 14:40:00 0.4/(0.4+0.5) 0.5/(0.5+0.5)
2016-05-10 15:20:00 0.5/(0.4+0.5) 0.5/(0.5+0.5)
```

Any idea to help me please?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas get column average](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037298/pandas-get-column-average)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming TIMESTAMP is a datetime type, here is one way:

```
df = df.set_index('TIMESTAMP')
r = df.ix['2016-05-10 14:40:00':'2016-05-10 15:20:00']
r/r.sum()

                     equipement1  equipement2
TIMESTAMP
2016-05-10 14:40:00     0.444444          0.5
2016-05-10 15:20:00     0.555556          0.5
```

Comment: Thank you Boud, but why we have to set as index TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Because it's very easy and powerful to work with datetimeindex in pandas. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html