# How to average of a column based on a group by using python pandas?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I have input like :

```
NAME            Geoid    Year   QTR Index 
'Abilene, TX    10180   1978    3   0
'Abilene, TX    10180   1978    4   0
'Abilene, TX    10180   1979    1   0
'Abilene, TX    10180   1979    2   0
'Decatur, IL    19500   1998    1   110.51
'Decatur, IL    19500   1998    2   110.48
'Decatur, IL    19500   1998    3   113.01
'Decatur, IL    19500   1998    4   114.16
'Fairbanks, AK  21820   1990    1   63.74
'Fairbanks, AK  21820   1990    2   70.68
'Fairbanks, AK  21820   1990    3   83.56
'Fairbanks, AK  21820   1990    4   83.95
```

The query that I want to convert to python from MYSQL is as this :

```
   SELECT  geoid, name, YEAR, AVG(index)
   FROM table_1
   WHERE geoid>0
   GROUP BY geoid, metro_name, YEAR;
```

The pythonic equivalent of AVG is mean is what i read online, but when I use mean it gives me a single value.

[pandas get column average/mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037298/pandas-get-column-average-mean)

But I want the output grouping the year and quarters like :

```
Name            Geoid   YEAR    AVG(index)
'Abilene, TX    10180   1978    0
'Abilene, TX    10180   1979    0
'Decatur, IL    19500   1998    111.75
'Fairbanks, AK  21820   1990    74.9875
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) or [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first for filtering and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate `mean`:

```
df1 = df.query('Geoid > 0').groupby(['NAME','Geoid','Year'], as_index=False)['Index'].mean()
print (df1)
             NAME  Geoid  Year     Index
0    'Abilene, TX  10180  1978    0.0000
1    'Abilene, TX  10180  1979    0.0000
2    'Decatur, IL  19500  1998  112.0400
3  'Fairbanks, AK  21820  1990   75.4825
```

---

```
df1 = df[df['Geoid'] > 0].groupby(['NAME','Geoid','Year'], as_index=False)['Index'].mean()
print (df1)
             NAME  Geoid  Year     Index
0    'Abilene, TX  10180  1978    0.0000
1    'Abilene, TX  10180  1979    0.0000
2    'Decatur, IL  19500  1998  112.0400
3  'Fairbanks, AK  21820  1990   75.4825
```