# What is the difference between using loc and using just square brackets to filter for columns in Pandas/Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've noticed three methods of selecting a column in a Pandas DataFrame:

**First method of selecting a column using loc:**

```
df_new = df.loc[:, 'col1']
```

**Second method - seems simpler and faster:**

```
df_new = df['col1']
```

**Third method - most convenient:**

```
df_new = df.col1
```

Is there a difference between these three methods? I don't think so, in which case I'd rather use the third method.

I'm mostly curious as to why there appear to be three methods for doing the same thing.

Comment: Or what about `df.col1`? All three of these are essentially equivalent for the very simple case of selecting a column. `.loc` will let you do much more than select a column. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31593201/pandas-iloc-vs-ix-vs-loc-explanation

Comment: They do the same thing for simple slices. loc is more explicit, especially when your columns are numbers.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. Good point re: df.col1, which is yet another method of column selection. I've actually looked at that other question before, several times. It's great for explaining loc and iloc. However, this question is about the other method: "df['col1']". I'm just confused as to why there are two (or three) equivalent ways of doing what appears to be the same thing.

Comment: The big disadvantage of 3rd method is that it's ambiguous when your column name is identical to an existing pandas attribute or method.  E.g. you name a column 'sum'.  Then if you type `df.sum`, what happens? (spoiler alert, nothing useful, although `df.sum()` still works luckily)  So 3rd way should be seen as a shortcut that is fine, but need to be careful with

Comment: A decent explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc

Comment: Related: [Python: Pandas Series - Why use loc? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886080/python-pandas-series-why-use-loc)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

In the following situations, they behave the same:

1. Selecting a single column (`df['A']` is the same as `df.loc[:, 'A']` -> selects column A)
2. Selecting a list of columns (`df[['A', 'B', 'C']]` is the same as `df.loc[:, ['A', 'B', 'C']]` -> selects columns A, B and C)
3. Slicing by rows (`df[1:3]` is the same as `df.iloc[1:3]` -> selects rows 1 and 2. Note, however, if you slice rows with `loc`, instead of `iloc`, you'll get rows 1, 2 and 3 assuming you have a [RangeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.RangeIndex.html). See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36955053/2285236).)

However, `[]` does not work in the following situations:

1. You can select a single row with `df.loc[row_label]`
2. You can select a list of rows with `df.loc[[row_label1, row_label2]]`
3. You can slice columns with `df.loc[:, 'A':'C']`

These three cannot be done with `[]`.
More importantly, if your selection involves both rows and columns, then assignment becomes problematic.

```
df[1:3]['A'] = 5
```

This selects rows 1 and 2 then selects column 'A' of the returning object and assigns value 5 to it. The problem is, the returning object might be a copy so this may not change the actual DataFrame. This raises  [SettingWithCopyWarning](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy). The correct way of making this assignment is:

```
df.loc[1:3, 'A'] = 5
```

With `.loc`, you are guaranteed to modify the original DataFrame. It also allows you to slice columns (`df.loc[:, 'C':'F']`), select a single row (`df.loc[5]`), and select a list of rows (`df.loc[[1, 2, 5]]`).

Also note that these two were not included in the API at the same time. `.loc` was added much later as a more powerful and explicit indexer. See [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38886211/2285236) for more detail.

---

Note: Getting columns with `[]` vs `.` is a completely different topic. `.` is only there for convenience. It only allows accessing columns whose names are valid Python identifiers (i.e. they cannot contain spaces, they cannot be composed of numbers...). It cannot be used when the names conflict with Series/DataFrame methods. It also cannot be used for non-existing columns (i.e. the assignment `df.a = 1` won't work if there is no column `a`). Other than that, `.` and `[]` are the same.

Comment: What do you mean with "the returning object might be a copy"? It is a bit confusing. Should I expect the value returned by `df[1:3]['A'] = 5` to be a copy or not?

Comment: @AlessioF That's the problem. We don't really know. pandas makes no guarantees about what returns from `df.__getitem__(...)`, and under the hood, the memory layout of the stored array can result in a view or a copy. In general, when you work on a dataframe with a single dtype, you get a view but that's not guaranteed. I believe they are working on a new approach instead of using BlockManager which is the main source of these issues.

Comment: And df.loc[] fails when the selection isn't found.

Answer (score 12):

`loc` is specially useful when the index is not numeric (e.g. a DatetimeIndex) because you can get *rows* with particular labels from the index:

```
df.loc['2010-05-04 07:00:00']
df.loc['2010-1-1 0:00:00':'2010-12-31 23:59:59 ','Price']
```

However `[]` is intended to get *columns* with particular names:

```
df['Price']
```

With `[]` you can also filter *rows*, but it is more elaborated:

```
df[df['Date'] < datetime.datetime(2010,1,1,7,0,0)]['Price']
```

Comment: I have `df_augmented['date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df_augmented.date_of_birth, format='mixed')` working, but not `df_augmented.loc[:, 'date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df_augmented.date_of_birth, format='mixed')` - the latter gives an Object column, the former a datetime64[ns]; why? are there differences between df['col'] and df[:, 'col'] in this case?

Comment: Looks like it is a Pandas peculiarity after 2.0.x; found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76766136/3429115). Confused me quite a bit!

Answer (score 3):

If you're confused which of these approaches is (at least) the recommended one for your use-case, take a look at this brief instructions from [pandas tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.2/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html):

- When **selecting subsets of data**, square brackets `[]` are used.
- Inside these brackets, you can use a single column/row label, a list
  of column/row labels, a slice of labels, a conditional expression or
  a colon.
- Select specific rows and/or columns using `loc` when using the row and
  column names
- Select specific rows and/or columns using `iloc` when using the
  positions in the table
- You can **assign new values** to a selection based on `loc`/`iloc`.

I highlighted some of the points to make their use-case differences even more clear.

Comment: What if you need to mix both methods, positions and names, for example the first row of the columna 'A'?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a difference between df.loc[] and df[] when you create dataframe with multiple columns.

You can refer to this question:
[Is there a nice way to generate multiple columns using .loc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496766/is-there-a-nice-way-to-generate-multiple-columns-using-loc?noredirect=1#comment95799033_54496766)

Here, you can't generate multiple columns using `df.loc[:,['name1','name2']]` but you can do by just using double bracket `df[['name1','name2']]`. (I wonder why they behave differently.)

Comment: Both methods worked when I tried, at least in the last Pandas version (1.5.3). see the [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/nfknQo2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There is an important difference in assignment. These two assignments are not equivalent:

```
df['j'] = pd.Series(...)
df.loc[:,'j'] = pd.Series(...)
```

- Indexing with `[...]` replaces the series. The new series comes with its own `dtype`, the existing `dtype` is discarded.
- Indexing with `loc[...]` replaces values, but reuses the existing series and its `dtype`, upcasting may occur to fit new values.

See how the old `int32` is ignored when using `[...]`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as npr

n = 4

# NumPy returns dtype int32
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'j': npr.randint(1, 10, n),
    'k': npr.randint(1, 10, n)})
print(df.dtypes)

# uint8 series
s = pd.Series(npr.randint(1, 10, n), dtype='uint8')

# Using [...]: uint8 series replaces uint32 series
df2 = df.copy()
df2['j'] = s
print(df2.dtypes)

# Using loc[...]: uint8 data upcasted to existing uint32
df3 = df.copy()
df3.loc[:,'j'] = s
print(df3.dtypes)
```

---

```
j    int32        ⇠ original dtype
k    int32
dtype: object

j    uint8        ⇠ with [...]
k    int32
dtype: object

j    int32        ⇠ with loc[...]
k    int32
dtype: object
```