# Is there a nice way to generate multiple columns using .loc?

Tags: python, pandas

After extracting strings using 
`extract_df = pd.str.extract('(\w+)\d+(\w+)', expand =True)` 
I get new dataframe with columns named 0 and 1.

I want to merge it back to my original dataframe with specific column names.

I thought I could generate multiple columns using .loc method, such as `data.loc[:,['name1','name2']] = extract_df` but it did not work.

I know I can change the column names and use `pd.merge` or `join` method but it seems inefficient to me.

Is there a nice way to generate multiple columns using .loc?

Or is there any other efficient way to handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Please share input dataframe and expected output

Comment: you should just be able to do `data[['name1', 'name2']] = extract_df`

Comment: Thanks Chris, data[['name1','name2']] worked. That makes me wonder why .loc didn't work though(generated empty blank). I guess it has to do with indexing.