# Subset a data frame according to pattern matches in a file.txt pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame such as

```
query   subject col1
A   dog ok
B   cat okl
C   cat oklp
D   frog    ok
E   cat ok
F   fox ok
```

and a file.txt such as:

```
dog
cat
```

and the idea is to only keep row that have a pattern present in the file.txt.
Here I should get :

```
query   subject col1
A   dog ok
B   cat okl
C   cat oklp
E   cat ok
```

I tried with :

```
file = open('file.txt').read()

df=[]
for row in tab['subject']:
 if row in file: 
   row.append(df)
```

but it does not seem to be the solution, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that your data frame is called *df*, this answer reads the file.txt also as a dataframe and [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) both data frames, resulting in the desired result - solution similar to an inner join from SQL:

```
>> df2 = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header= None, names=['subject'])
>> pd.merge(df, df2, on='subject')

    query   subject col1
0   A       dog     ok
1   B       cat     okl
2   C       cat     oklp
3   E       cat     ok
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`df.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to grab specific rows where a criterion is met, and [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to check whether something in your dataframe shows up in a given list. First make a list of the entries in your file:

```
vals = []  # placeholder for our file contents
with open('file.txt', 'r') as a_file:
    for line in a_file:
        vals.append(line)
```

Next select rows where the subject column is one of the values read from your file. Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
new_df = df.loc[df.subject.isin(vals)]
```

Side note: you almost never want to iterate over a dataframe. There are exceptions to this, but generally speaking if you find yourself iterating on a dataframe (e.g. `for row in df:`), you can rewrite that piece of code to take advantage of vectorized functions in Pandas which are *much* more efficient.

Comment: i think if you remove the loc you still should be fine. :)

Comment: Thanks very much is does exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @anky_91 you're right it should still work, but `loc` is the preferred method. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411543/2464597 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/38886211/2464597 for some reasons why. Generally I'd say it's best to get in the habit of using the preferred method; in this case `loc`.

Comment: @Engineero cool, thanks for sharing. Not necessary here is what i meant incase you wanted to reduce operation. :) already upvoted