# df['colimn_name'] vs df.loc[:, 'colimn_name']

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like more info. on the answer to the following question:

1. df[‘Name’] and 2. df.loc[:, ‘Name’], where:

df = pd.DataFrame(['aa', 'bb', 'xx', 'uu'], [21, 16, 50, 33], columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

Choose the correct option:

1. 1 is the view of original dataframe and 2 is a copy of original
   dataframe
2. 2 is the view of original dataframe and 1 is a copy of
   original dataframe
3. Both are copies of original dataframe
4. Both are views of original dataframe

I found more than one answer online but not sure. I think the answer is number 2 but when i tried x = df['name'] then x[0] = 'cc' then print(df) I saw that the change appeared in the original dataframe. So how the changed appeared in the original dataframe although I also got this warining:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

I just want to know more about the difference between the two and weather one is really a copy of the original dataframe or not. Thank you.

Comment: Linked with [What is the difference between using loc and using just square brackets to filter for columns in Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411543/11154841).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of them are `VIEW` only, if you need a copy we need

```
df['Name'].copy(). 
df.loc[:, 'Name'].copy()
```

`loc` here can give you access to `index` and `column` at the same time, also avoid chain slice

```
df.loc[cond1, cond2]
```

Notice above `loc` can also pass condition rather than only column names

```
df.loc[:, df.columns=='Name']
#df[df.columns=='Name'] this will return error
```

Example for Div

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
df
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
df[df.columns==0]
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ```

Comment: Condition can also be given in `df[]`

Comment: @DivyesshMaheshwari you sure ?

Comment: @DivyesshMaheshwari if condition that is index slice in []

Comment: I am sure and any condition can be placed brother

Comment: @DivyesshMaheshwari try the example

Comment: The condition can be given as `df[df['0'] > 1]`

Comment: @DivyesshMaheshwari this is index slice condition ...I mean the column axis=1

Comment: Yes that is what loc is for

Comment: The df[] has its own condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218103/discussion-between-divyessh-maheshwari-and-yoben-s).

Answer (score 0):

Both are the views of original dataframe
One can be used to add more columns in dataframe and one is used for specifically getting a view of a cell or row or column in dataframe.