# Best practice for slicing Pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Which line of code is recommended to slice a Pandas dataframe based on condition?
First method, based on `.loc[]`:

```
data_sorted_by_UDRS_laterality_Y_H_final = data_sorted_by_UDRS_laterality_Y_H.loc[(data_sorted_by_UDRS_laterality_Y_H['ECHELLE_H/Y_T0'] < 3) & (data_sorted_by_UDRS_laterality_Y_H['LATERALITY_BASED_ON_UPDRS'] != 'BILAT')]
```

Second method :

```
data_sorted_by_UDRS_laterality_Y_H_other = data_sorted_by_UDRS_laterality_Y_H[(data_sorted_by_UDRS_laterality_Y_H['LATERALITY_BASED_ON_UPDRS'] != 'BILAT') &  (data_sorted_by_UDRS_laterality_Y_H['ECHELLE_H/Y_T0'] < 3)]
```

Is there another way to do this conditional slicing easily within Pandas?

Comment: Already discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409128/what-is-the-difference-between-using-loc-and-using-just-square-brackets-to-filte

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between using loc and using just square brackets to filter for columns in Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409128/what-is-the-difference-between-using-loc-and-using-just-square-brackets-to-filte)

Comment: As a third option you could also use [`df.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to express this condition: `data_sorted_by_UDRS_laterality_Y_H.query('"LATERALITY_BASED_ON_UPDRS" != "BILAT" and "ECHELLE_H/Y_T0" < 3`