# I'm having a hard time understanding what pandas.DataFrame.loc does in this line of code

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tracing a basic machine learning python code to learn the basics and i stumbled upon these two lines of code:

```
data.loc[:,'symboling'] = data['symboling'].astype('object')
data.rename(columns={'symboling':'riskScore'},inplace=True)
```

first of all "data" is the csv file after being read with panda.read_csv and "symboling" is one of the column labels (the first one).

I understood the second line from the Pandas docs but I dont get what the first line does at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line converts the `symboling` column to `object` and replaces it in the dataframe.

On the left-hand side, `data.loc[:,'symboling']` selects all rows (the `:` part is a slice) and the `symboling` column.

`loc` is probably being used here to avoid a [SettingWithCopy warning](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing), which might occur if the author had written:

```
data['symboling'] = data['symboling'].astype('object')
```

See also: [What is the difference between using loc and using just square brackets to filter for columns in Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48409128/1288)

Comment: i think i get it now, thank you!