# pandas - mask works on whole dataframe but on selected columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, in-place

I was replacing values in columns and noticed that if use `mask` on all the dataframe, it will produce expected results, but if I used it against selected columns with `.loc`, it won't change any value.

Can you explain why and tell if it is expected result?

You can try with a dataframe dt, containing 0 in columns:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
dt.mask(lambda x: x == 0, np.nan, inplace=True)
# will replace all zeros to nan, OK.
```

But:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
columns = list('BC')
dt.loc[:, columns].mask(lambda x: x == 0, np.nan, inplace=True)
# won't cange anything. I excpet B, C columns to have values replaced
```

Comment: Very interesting question, I tried to answer it.

Comment: grazie @Massifox ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc) functions returns a copy of the dataframe. On this copy you are applying the [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html?highlight=mask#pandas.DataFrame.mask) function that perform the operation in place on the data. You can't do this on a one-liner, otherwise the memory copy remains inaccessible. To get access to that memory area you have to split the code into 2 lines, to get a reference to that memory area:

```
tmp = dt.loc[:, columns]
tmp.mask(tmp[columns] == 0, np.nan, inplace=True)
```

and then you can go and update the dataframe:

```
dt[columns] = tmp
```

Not using the inplace update of the mask function, on the other hand, you can do everything with one line of code

```
dt[columns] = dt.loc[:, columns].mask(dt[columns] == 0, np.nan, inplace=False)
```

**Extra**:
If you want to better understand the use of the inplace method in pandas, I recommend you read these posts:

- [Understanding inplace=True in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true-in-pandas)
- [In pandas, is inplace = True considered harmful, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570984/in-pandas-is-inplace-true-considered-harmful-or-not)
- [What is the difference between using loc and using just square brackets to filter for columns in Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411543/9302488)

Comment: thank you for the explaination, can you clarify this: dt[columns].mask(lambda x: x == 0, np.nan, inplace=True) // will give: `SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame`  while `inplace=False` will not give error. why so ? I would expect not because `inplace=True` does not make a copy. It's confusing.. so you say one problem is the use of inplace, and the other use of loc ? can I avoid using loc ? (see answer below)

Comment: with `dt[columns]` exactly the same reasoning applies as applied to the `dt.loc[:,columns]` case, so you need 2 passes using a temporary variable. I will add in the "Extra" section a link that will better explain to you the use indexing with loc and with the notation with brackets.

Comment: basically inplace is useless, I think pandas either make the inplace prevent copy or need to remove this option. for numpy and scipy inplace really means no-copy

Answer (score 2):

i guess it's because the DataFrame.loc property is just giving access to a slice of your dataframe and you are masking a copy of the dataframe so it doesn't affect the data.

you can try this instead:

```
dt[columns] = dt[columns].mask(dt[columns] == 0)
```

Comment: Hi @SergFSM can you clarify : I was trying `dt[columns].mask(lambda x: x == 0, np.nan, inplace=True)` and would expect and inplace access to data, non masking a copy, but masking the very same dataset. But your solution works. Can you explain why ?

Comment: @user305883, `df[]` performs in the same manner as `df.loc[]`, it slices columns when `loc` slices cells

Comment: Hi @SergFSM, thank you. I am solicited to mark an answer as correct, your answer is synthetic and perfectly fine for me, but eventually I ticked the other one for the explanations and links the author added - I anyway wanted to write a comment to say thank you and hope you don't feel bad about !

Comment: @user305883, no worries, it's OK