# In Python, what is the difference between df["row_name"] and df.loc["row_name"]

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pandas-loc

I am trying to add another row to my data Frame

When I use  df["new_row"] = [5, True, "joe", 20] , I get the error

```
ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (11)
```

but if I use df.loc["new_row"] = [5, True, "joe", 20], I can succesfully add a new row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between using loc and using just square brackets to filter for columns in Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409128/what-is-the-difference-between-using-loc-and-using-just-square-brackets-to-filte)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about the difference, in `pandas`, `df["colname"]` is used to access a column of a given data frame.

`loc[r,c]` is used to access specific cells within that data frame in the order of row and column. So, if you use `df.loc[r]`, it will access the entire row.

In your case,`df.loc['new_row']`, creates a new row, at which you are inserting `[5, True, "joe", 20]`