# what is the effect of loc in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have this minimal reproducible example

```
import pandas as pd
 
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, None, 1],
                "B":[7, 2, 54, 3, None],
                "C":[20, 16, 11, 3, 8],
                "D":[14, 3, None, 2, 6]})
 
index_ = ['Row_1', 'Row_2', 'Row_3', 'Row_4', 'Row_5']
 
df.index = index_
print(df)

# Option 1
result = df[['A', 'D']]
print(result)

# Option 2
result = df.loc[:, ['A', 'D']]
print(result)
```

What is the effect on using `loc` or not. The results are quite similar.
I ask this in preparation for a more complex question in which I have been instructed to use loc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between using loc and using just square brackets to filter for columns in Pandas/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409128/what-is-the-difference-between-using-loc-and-using-just-square-brackets-to-filte)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that `df[['A', 'D']]` is a weak reference to `df` (here on pandas 2.1.2).

```
result1 = df[['A', 'D']]
print(result1._is_copy)
#<weakref at 0x7f34261b69d0; to 'DataFrame' at 0x7f34260e9590>

result2 = df.loc[:, ['A', 'D']]
print(result2._is_copy)
# None
```

In both cases, this is not a view:

```
print(result1._is_view, result2._is_view)
# False False
```

This behavior has changed with the pandas versions.

Is this important?

It depends what you want to do. In most cases no.

The first approach can however, in specific cases, trigger  `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
result1 = df[['A', 'D']]
s1 = result1['A']
s1[:] = 1
# SettingWithCopyWarning: 
# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

result2 = df.loc[:, ['A', 'D']]
s2 = result2['A']
s2[:] = 1
# no Warning
```

Comment: Does that mean that in the first case, result1 is a separate dataframe (a copy) while in the second is just a view?

Comment: @KansaiRobot it's a bit tricky and changing with pandas versions. In most cases it shouldn't matter, however in specific edge cases this can trigger a `SettingWithCopyWarning` (see update). What are you trying to do in your case?

Comment: Yes, this is very much related with the next question I plan to ask. It is interesting that result1 is a "weak reference". I am trying to solve the `SettingWithCopyWarning` with loc but I haven't been able to do it.

Comment: I am trying to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77438038/dash-script-that-filters-and-modifies-dataframes-give-warning

Answer (score 1):

Using `.loc` is mostly better in complex operations but also for clarity. For example:

- If your indexing involves both row and column labels, `.loc` makes the
  code more readable and consistent.
- Avoid ambiguity when you have say number-named columns
- Also when you want to assign values to specific cells
- Chained indexing
- Readability

Answer (score 1):

Both options are equivalent when selecting columns, but the first option is generally more concise and commonly used for simple column selection tasks. The second option, which uses .loc, may be more useful when you need to specify both rows and columns explicitly, or when you want to apply more complex selection criteria.

Answer (score 0):

No effect above, as far as I can tell. .loc is useful when you want to select specific rows.