# dash script that filters and modifies dataframes give warning

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have the following script

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd


# The warning has not been resolved

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Eve'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 22, 35, 28],
    'Salary': [50000, 60000, 45000, 70000, 55000]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("DataFrame Filtering and Augmentation"),

    html.Label("Filter by Age:"),
    dcc.Input(id='age-filter', type='number', value=30),

    dcc.Graph(id='result-plot')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('result-plot', 'figure'),
    [Input('age-filter', 'value')]
)
def update_dataframe(age_filter):
    # Filter the DataFrame based on age
    filtered_df = df[df['Age'] < age_filter]

    # Augment the filtered DataFrame with a new column
    filtered_df['SalarySquared'] = filtered_df['Salary'] ** 2

    # Create a bar chart based on the augmented DataFrame
    figure = {
        'data': [
            {'x': filtered_df['Name'], 'y': filtered_df['SalarySquared'], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Salary Squared'},
        ],
        'layout': {
            'title': f'Salary Squared for Individuals with Age < {age_filter}',
            'xaxis': {'title': 'Name'},
            'yaxis': {'title': 'Salary Squared'}
        }
    }

    return figure

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True,port=8070)
```

Even though this script works and gives me what I need, it shows a warning

> Dash is running on http://127.0.0.1:8070/
>
> - Serving Flask app 'cashFilterCalculations'
> - Debug mode: on
>
> C:\path\cashFilterCalculations.py:60: SettingWithCopy
>
> Warning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
> Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

I have tried to solve this replacing the function with

```
def update_dataframe(age_filter):
    # Filter the DataFrame based on age using .loc
    filtered_df = df.loc[df['Age'] < age_filter]

    # Augment the filtered DataFrame with a new column using .loc
    filtered_df.loc[:, 'SalarySquared'] = filtered_df['Salary'] ** 2 # HERE

    # Create a bar chart based on the augmented DataFrame
    figure = {
        'data': [
            {'x': filtered_df['Name'], 'y': filtered_df['SalarySquared'], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Salary Squared'},
        ],
        'layout': {
            'title': f'Salary Squared for Individuals with Age < {age_filter}',
            'xaxis': {'title': 'Name'},
            'yaxis': {'title': 'Salary Squared'}
        }
    }

    return figure
```

but still I got the warning produced by the line marked "HERE"

Is there a way to solve this warning?

Then again this warning seems to alert that " this may not change the actual DataFrame." and since I do not want to modity the original dataframe?? should I just ignore it? Or not? I am confused about this