# pandas how to write a query

Tags: sql, python-2.7, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Based off this
[pandas get column average/mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037298/pandas-get-column-average-mean)

I can create a simple calculated field like this:
My Query

```
df = pd.read_sql("select range_start, range_end  from "+table+" group by  range_start, range_end", conn)
```

creates this table:

```
Start   Stop
4385159 4499467
4175786 4352309
342426  354137
5591040 5600392
```

What I want to do is inject a column that has the diff which I can do by doing this:

```
df2['Diff'] = df2['Stop'] - df2['Start']
```

Now my table looks like this:

```
Start   End      Diff
4385159 4499467 114308
4175786 4352309 176523
342426  354137  11711
```

My problem is how do I write a query that will return results:

```
df = pd.read_sql("select Diff  from "+table+" where Diff < Xnumber group by  Diff", conn)
```

I think I need to put a query inside of a query in jupyter (pandas). to do something like this:

```
df = pd.read_sql("select (df2['Stop'] - df2['Start']) as df2['Diff'] where (df2['Stop'] - df2['Start']) < Xnumber group by (df2['Stop'] - df2['Start'])",conn)
```

^ that didnt work but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but could you just create the new column directly in pandas, without any querying?

```
df['Diff'] = df2['Stop'] - df2['Start']
```

Comment: that works, but I was trying to use it as apart of a query so I can add a condition, see my answer below. but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
df6 = pd.read_sql("select (Start - Stop) as Diff from "+table+" where <condition>",conn)
```