# average distance for a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, math

I have a data frame like this:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10, 16, 7, 2, 5]})
```

How can I find the average distance for the column 'a'? For example, the average distance between 10 and 16 = (10 + 6) / 2 = 8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas get column average/mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037298/pandas-get-column-average-mean)

Comment: @RandomGuy No, I want the average distance, not just average; for example, if I have just 10 and 6, my desired output is 8, but the average is 13.

Comment: What do you call the average distance? On your example, what is it supposed to output?

Comment: @RandomGuy considers 10 and 16, so the distance is 6; therefore, the average distance is (10+6)/2 = 8. Actually, my question is can I compute this metric for any two consecutive rows in the data frame?

Comment: So the "average distance" of x and y is (x + (y - x))/2?

Comment: @Joni Exactly, I want to apply this for the whole of the column.

Comment: So, is it `sample.shift(-1) / 2`?

Comment: @MustafaAydın Yeah, I think so. Can you explain how does it work?

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether).

Comment: @MustafaAydın Sure, thanks for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the math you described, it is equivalent to "next value divided by 2". So we get the next values by shifting the series and then `/ 2` to halve them:

```
# data itself
>>> sample

    a
0  10
1  16
2   7
3   2
4   5

# shift the values upwards by 1 unit so 2nd becomes 1st etc.
# and the last becomes NaN as there is nothing below it to replace
>>> sample.shift(-1)

      a
0  16.0
1   7.0
2   2.0
3   5.0
4   NaN

# per your formula
>>> sample.shift(-1) / 2

     a
0  8.0
1  3.5
2  1.0
3  2.5
4  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

The "average distance" of x and y is defined as (x + (y - x))/2.

That's just y/2. Drop the first row and divide the rest by 2: `sample.a[1:]/2`