# Accessing columns row by row in dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 300 columns, I'm trying to calculate the mean of the columns in this dataframe, but I don't know how to change the columns.

```
count=0
for i in range(0,len(df)):
  count=count+1
  mean = statistics.mean(df.A1)
  print('C',count, " ", mean, sep= "")
```

**I need to get the column names from A1 to A300 row by row. I didn't want to do this manually**

My dataframe columns like A1,A2,A3.. A.300

how can i step by step change this columns name?

Comment: *I'm trying to calculate the mean of the columns in this dataframe*: have you tried `df.mean()`, no need to iterate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas get column average/mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037298/pandas-get-column-average-mean)

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through columns,

```
cols = df.columns
for col in cols:
  mean = df[col].mean()
  print(col, mean)
```

Comment: Not work: ` TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator ` @RG_RG

Comment: can you share your dataframe?

Comment: If you just want mean, you can use `df.mean()` function.

Comment: I don't need a function, i need a loop for the every columns mean. Like. A1 means, A2 means... A300 means. so i need change the column name. But i don't know i make this.

Comment: `df.mean()` is an inbuilt method. just use it like the code above, it works.

Comment: you don't need to loop like A1, A2 etc. just looping `df.columns` itself loops the columns.