# Pandas script is taking along time to run

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

This code is meant to find the average promotion value in a given month in a two-year period. In total there are about 11,000 rows in the data set that need to be looked over. The code has been running for 5 minutes and the results still haven't been posted. I'm a still very novice in my coding career so any tips onto better optimize code for faster completion times would be appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\james.rush\df_LG.csv')
df.head()
Promos = []
Avg_Promo = []
Dates = []

#This function is used to determine the Average Promotion during any given month/year
def Promo_Avg(Date):
    for x in df['Date']: #For all dates in dataframe
        Promo_Value = df.loc[df['Date'] == Date, 'Promo'] #Locate the corresponding promo given the provided date
        Promos.append(Promo_Value) #Add that Promo to the list of Promos for that month, will need list length later
    Average_Promotion = sum(Promos)/len(Promos) #Average Promotion during the given month
    if Average_Promotion not in Avg_Promo: #Prevents Duplicates
        Avg.append(Average_Promotion)
    if Date not in Dates: #If the Current Date being Checked is not in list, add to list. This will prevent Duplicates
        Dates.append(Dates) 

Function_Dates = [
    'January2020',
    'Febuary2020',
    'March2020'
                 ]
for x in Function_Dates:
Promo_Avg(x)
```

Comment: 1) Much faster to use mean function on DataFrame column e.g. [pandas get column average/mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037298/pandas-get-column-average-mean)  2) It would be better if the function just returned the average given a date rather than also updating Avg_Promo,  Dates (i.e. functions should not do unrelated things).

Comment: It would be helpful to provide some lines from the data file you're processing.

Comment: @DarrylG Thank you for the suggestion, i'll try this function out

Comment: Using Pandas mean, the function simplifies to:  `def promo_avg(date): return df[df.Date==date].Promos.mean()` where I used the Python naming convention for variables and function names.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are looping over your dataframe with df.loc but *without considering your x variable from the for loop*, this for loop seems to be useless then.
So you are looping something like 121,000,000 over your df, that might be why it is slow.

**Some more details about your question:**
*Credits to @DarrylG's comment.*

You are trying to

> find the average promotion value in a given month in a two-year period

This breaks up in 3 parts :
Find, project and average.

```py
def promo_avg(date):
  return df[df.Date==date].Promos.mean()
```

Seems to do the job, let's see the three parts in details:
**Find:**
`df[df.Date==date]` means from `df` find lines where column `Date` corresponds to `date`

**Project:**
What I mean by project is the [projection from the relational algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)).
The goal is to restrict your data to some specific columns, in your case, the column `Promo`.
`df[df.Date==date].Promo` your previous Find part returns a dataframe, so you can project your data simply by doing `.Promo`.

**Average:**
After your projection, you still have a dataframe and all the advantages it comes with, including an averaging function.
`df[df.Date==date].Promos.mean()` should do the trick

I hope it was clear and useful :)