# Finding average age in sheet using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJWnu.png)

How can I find the average age for each row in this example. Each columns has its own age ranging from 0 to 90. I have read the csv with pandas.

Comment: Just lookup 'average' in pandas documentation, it's a simple function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas get column average/mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037298/pandas-get-column-average-mean)

Comment: I does not work, ideally. The problem is that it only takes the average of the sum of each row, but it does not take into account how many occourances of each age. For example If there is 4 people that are aged 4. I need to mulitply 4 with 4

Comment: Does this work? Create new column with averages of each row using `df['mean'] = df.mean(axis=1)`

Comment: No it does not work, i need to first sum up how many people has a certain age and then multiply it by the acctual age

Answer (score 0):

I Assume all the age-related columns are named like Age_0, Age_1, Age_2, ...

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")

ages = np.array([int(c.split("_")[-1]) for c in df.filter(regex="^Age_\d+$").columns])
df.loc[:, "avg_age"] = (df.filter(regex="^Age_\d+$").values * ages).sum(axis=1) / df.filter(regex="^Age_\d+$").values.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: thank you, but i get this error message

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  copy.loc[:, "avg_age"] = (copy.filter(regex="^Age_\d+$").values * ages).sum(axis=1) / copy.filter(regex="^Age_\d+$").values.sum(axis=1)

Comment: it's a warning, not an error. the reason is that you have (at least) a row in which the sum of the number of observations is zero. For that row, the resulting `avg_age` would be NaN which is alright. if you want to get problematic row, try:
df.loc[df.filter(regex="^Age_\d+$").sum(axis="columns") == 0, :]

Comment: what should i replace it with?

Comment: you don't need to replace the observations with anything. In the average column, you will have some NaNs which is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are the amount of people per age, here is one solution.

(Potentially not the fastest for large amount of data)

```
highest_age = 90

def row_age(x):
    sum_age = 0
    sum_people = 0
    for i in range(0, highest_age + 1):
        people = x[f"age_{i}"]
        sum_people += people
        sum_age += people * i
    if sum_people > 0:
        return sum_age / sum_people


df["average_age"] = df.apply(row_age, axis=1)
```