# How to store dataframe mean as a column wise

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If we have a dataframe like the below one

```
    A   B   C
0   5   3   8
1   5   3   9
2   8   4   9
```

We can calculate the mean using `df.mean()` and the output looks like

```
A    6.000000
B    3.333333
C    8.666667
dtype: float64
```

Now, I want to save the mean in a column-wise format like the below one.

```
     A     B     C
0   6.0   3.3   8.6
```

How can I do this?

I have gone through a couple of posts but have not gotten any idea and the sample data was taken from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037298/pandas-get-column-average-mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `to_frame` then transpose the result:

```py
df.mean().to_frame().T

#output
    A      B         C
0  6.0  3.333333  8.666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataFrame constructor:

```
out = pd.DataFrame([df.mean()])
```

Output:

```
     A         B         C
0  6.0  3.333333  8.666667
```